# Loading Multiple Item in one tag

Tags: ajax, jquery-load

I'm trying to build a "windows" like application and I want the user to be able to load multiple page. Currently I have the following request :

```
// Open the Profile Search Windows
$("#MainMenuProfileButton").click(function() {
    $("#ProgramContent").load("forms/ProfileSearch.html",function() {
    // Attach Event to the Profile Search Windows
        $(".ProfileFormSearch").draggable({ handle: ".FormTopTitle" });;

    });
});
```

But when I run the command twice, instead of opening a second windows (or append the html to the existing one) it will reload the same window... Any Idea how I can manage this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(".ProfileFormSearch").draggable({ handle: ".FormTopTitle" });
```

You could use:

```
$(".ProfileFormSearch:not(.init)").addClass('init').draggable({ handle: ".FormTopTitle" });
```

This way you can be sure that a draggable won't be re-initialized.

#### Edit:

To dynamically load with ajax, you should do:

```
$.get('forms/ProfileSearch.html', function(data){ $("#ProgramContent").append( data );  })
```

Comment: The Problem is that I want the user to insert two or three "Profilesearch.html" in the Program content. but this code only allow me to ad one.

Comment: oh, so you basically have a ajax issue, not draggable :) See my edit.